# mediaRecorder!!.prepare() generate invalid surface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm trying to make a small video clip (20 seconds) when opening an activity and save to galery, I use a holder callback and the surface is created, however it generates an error. this is my code.

```
private lateinit var surfaceView: SurfaceView
private lateinit var surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder

class CamActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SurfaceHolder.Callback {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam)

    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surface_view)
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.holder
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    val surface = surfaceHolder.surface
    mediaRecorder?.setPreviewDisplay(surface)
    this.startRecording()
}
override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {// El SurfaceHolder está listo, podríamos inicializar la cámara aquí
    try {// Obtén una superficie válida del holder
        val surface = holder.surface
        mediaRecorder?.setPreviewDisplay(surface)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error al establecer la superficie de vista previa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
    // Cambios en el SurfaceHolder, si es necesario
}

override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    // El SurfaceHolder es destruido, liberamos recursos
}

//Region Camera functions
private fun startRecording() {

    try {// Obtén una superficie válida del holder
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView?.holder!!
        surfaceHolder?.addCallback(this);
        val surface = surfaceHolder?.surface

        if (checkPermissions()) {
            try {
                // Configurar MediaRecorder
                mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
                mediaRecorder!!.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT)
                //mediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT)
                mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                mediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
                //mediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                mediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000)
                mediaRecorder!!.setVideoFrameRate(30)
                mediaRecorder!!.setVideoSize(640, 480)
                mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(getOutputFile().absolutePath)

                mediaRecorder!!.setPreviewDisplay(surface)
                mediaRecorder!!.prepare()
                mediaRecorder!!.start()

                // Detener la grabación después de 20 segundos
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    delay(VIDEO_DURATION)
                    stopRecording()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error al establecer la vista previa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

in the frist lines of the function startRecording(), create the surface, in the debug this line load the value (or similar)

```
"Surface(name=null)/@0x1a03f3c"
```

I think this is correct, but in the line mediaRecorder!!.prepare() generate the error

```
java.io.IOException: invalid preview surface
```

I appreciate any help or suggestion.
PD:Audio not is important for me

I have tried several things from forcing the creation with surfaceCreated(), with delay, and nothing works, I appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably happens when you try to `setPreviewDisplay` in the Activity's `onCreate` method because the Surface doesn't exist yet. You should only do it in the `surfaceCreated` callback.

Comment: I have tried, it continues with the error.. :(

Comment: Try to delete all lines after the line `surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);` in `onCreate()`. And call `startRecording()` after the surface is created.